# Juju GUI and Landscape GUI not accessible from different subnet

Tags: juju, gui

We have deployed auto pilot on Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS with Juju and MAAS. I am unable to access Juju GUI from a different subnet. It is accessible on the same subnet. The Architecture for environment is that we have two subnets  public and private, the MAAS nodes are connected to both the subnets and JUJU controller & landscape is connected to private subnets and there is no firewall between the subnets. The JUJU controller and Landscape are pinging from external network.

Kindly please help.

Comment: did you deploy the juju-gui charm of just using your juju-gui from your model based on your model uuid?